# Practice test - simplifying expressions

Tags: arithmetic

another question I am stuck on in a practice test.
The question is $$\frac{5^{2011} - 5^{2009} +24}{ 5^{2009} +1}$$
Can you cancel out the $5^{2009}$ or not?

Comment: That would be wishful thinking.

Comment: Not.  Definitely not.

Comment: What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Canceling $5^{2009}$ out gives $$\frac{25-1+\frac{24}{5^{2009}}}{1+\frac{1}{5^{2009}}}=24.$$

Comment: Hint: use $a^x - a^y= a^y (a^x-1) $ and $(b^2-1) =(b-1)(b+1) $.  Together the answer becomes something *very* nice.

Comment: Hint: $5^2-1=(5+1)(5-1)=6*4=24$.

Answer (score 1):

$5^{2011}-5^{2009}+24=5^{2009}(5^2-1)+24=5^{2009}*24+24=24(5^{2009}+1)$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{5^{2011}-5^{2009}+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{5^{2009+2}-5^{2009}+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{5^{2009}\cdot5^{2}-5^{2009}+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{5^{2009}\cdot25-5^{2009}+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{5^{2009}\cdot(25-1)+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{5^{2009}\cdot24+24}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$\dfrac{24\cdot(5^{2009}+1)}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$24\cdot\dfrac{5^{2009}+1}{5^{2009}+1}=$

$24$

Answer (score 1):

You really should have observed that $5^{2011}-5^{2009} = 5^{2009}(5^2-1)$, and take it from there.

With also $24 = 5^2-1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{5^{2011} - 5^{2009} +24}{ 5^{2009} +1} & = \frac{5^2(5^{2009}+1) - 5^2 - (5^{2009} + 1) + 1 +24}{ 5^{2009} +1} \\
 & = 25 - 1 + \frac{\;\;\cdots\;\;}{5^{2009} +1}
\end{align}
$$